# How to use the return value of a function with parameters inside another function

Tags: c++, function

All these functions are outside the int main():

```
int func1(int x) {

    int v1 = 6 * x;
    return v1; // the input argument will be 2, so v1 = 12
}

int func2(){
    int v2 = func1() / 4; // It's suppose to be 12 / 4
    //I get "too few arguments in function call"
 }
```

I know `func1()` inside 2nd function lacks arguments, that's the reason for the "too few arguments" warning. What I want to know is how can I use the return value of `func1()` inside `func2()`, as a value to a variable.

Like this, with functions without parameters, which work fine:

```
     int sum() {

        int v1 = 10;
        int v2 = 4;
        int v3 = v1 + v2; // 10 + 4 = 14
        return v3; // v3 = 14
    }

    int sub() {

        int v4 = sum() - 7; // 14 - 7 = 7;
        return v4; // v4 = 7
 }
```

Thanks.

EDIT : Sorry, I thought I had made myself clear when I said I understood the reason for the warning. My mistake.

I need the input from the user in function 1 to be variable.

So, in main(), when the user is prompted to give a number, it will be passed to function 1. The argument is not fixed, it is variable.

EDIT 2:
Here's the idea behind the main:

```
int main() {
    int x = 0;
    cin >> x;
    func1(x); // send user input to func1, then to func2
    int e = func2(); // return result of above to int e
    cout << e << "\n";


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this error because you have to give the function all the arguments it needs. You are not giving an argument to a function so it will not work. sum() doesnt receive any arguments so it has to be called like this

```
sum()
```

func1() takes one argument so either change it to a function that takes no arguments

```
int func1() {

    int v1 = 6 * 2;
    return v1; // the input argument will be 2, so v1 = 12
}
```

but it shows that you havent thought about what you are doing and its kinda useless

or call it like this without changing the function

```
int v2 = func1(2) / 4;
```

EDIT
So you can change func2 to also get one argument and pass it to func1

```
int func2(int x){
    int v2 = func1(x) / 4;
 }
```

and in main do this

```
int x;
cin>>x;
func2(x);
```

also small thing your func2() should return int but you dont have a return statement

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Should be:

```
int func2(){
    int v2 = func1(2) / 4; // It's suppose to be 12 / 4
    return v2;
}
```

Whenever you call a function, you have to pass the parameters it requires.

You get "too few arguments" because you're not passing the right amount of arguments!

Comment: But I need the argument to be variable. I expressed myself poorly. Already fixed the post. Sorry.

Comment: @JohnnyJohnny Then pass the number to func2 as an argument, then pass it to func1 inside func2.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED ANWSER**

If you need the variable to be a user input, then try this:

```
int main() {
    int x = 0;
    cin >> x;
    int y = func1(x); // send user input to func1, then to func2
    int e = func2(y); // return result of above to int e
    cout << e << "\n";
}
```

And then your functions should look like this:

```
int func1(int x) {
    int v1 = 6 * x;
    return v1; // the input argument will be 2, so v1 = 12
}

int func2(int x){
    int v2 = func1(x) / 4; // It's suppose to be 12 / 4
 }
```

Comment: Your code potentially has UB due to reading of an uninitialised variable. **Check your I/O for success**

Comment: @Dat Hat Thanks. Almost there. Also, did you ask?

Comment: @JohnnyJohnny what do you mean by `did you ask?'

Comment: @DatHa For anyone's opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The function needs an argument, so pass it an argument.

It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify your question? From my understanding you're doing what you want correctly.

```
double add_5(double x) {
    return x + 5;
}
double nested_method(double x) {
    double myVariable = add_5(x); //my variable = x + 5
    //other code//
    return myVariable;
}
int main() {
double myInput = 123;
    std::cout << nested_method(myInput) << std::endl; //output should = 128
}
```

If a method asks for 'n' parameters to call the method you must give it each of those 'n' parameters (of the apropriate type).

*ignoring overloads / default values etc*

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but this works for me:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int func1(int x)
{
    int v1 = 6 * x;
    return v1; // the input argument will be 2, so v1 = 12
}

int func2(int x)
{
  int v2 = func1(x) / 4; // It's suppose to be 12 / 4
  return v2;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  printf( "%i\n", func2( 2 ) );
  return 0;
}

$ gcc test.c

$ ./a.out
3
```